# How Do you set MOTW on an Executable

Tags: c++, ntfs

How do you set MOTW (Mark of the Web) on an executable that is downloaded from the internet?

Comment: You have to heat up the iron first.

Comment: I wish to manually set the MOTW flag on files.

Comment: You mean the Security section "This file came from another computer..." on the file properties page? It's stored in an alternate file stream http://superuser.com/questions/38476/this-file-came-from-another-computer-how-can-i-unblock-all-the-files-in-a/38494#38494 I'm not sure what the API is to access that but there's some documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364404%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: So I hear that browsers, manually set a MOTW tag on files to indicate they have come from the internet. That is how u distinguish

Comment: @Rup and @Hans, why not put your comments in answers, since that is what they are, and let them be scored and/or chosen? Mis-using comments like this leaves questions appearing unanswered and fouls up SO.

Comment: @beldaz :-) Sorry. I commented because it's not the full answer, and because I wanted to clarify the question before it got more down-votes / closed. It's not worth an answer without the name of the stream and a spec of what should be written to it, and I don't know that. I don't object to someone taking what we're written and filling in the gaps as an answer, and I'll vote for it.

Answer (score 11):

This data is stored in an [NTFS alternative file stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364404%28VS.85%29.aspx) alongside an executable. The stream is called [Zone.Identifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff469212%28PROT.10%29.aspx):

> Windows® Internet Explorer® uses the stream name Zone.Identifier for storage of URL security zones.
>   The fully qualified form is `sample.txt:Zone.Identifier:$DATA`
>   The stream is a simple text stream of the form:
>
> ```
>    [ZoneTransfer]
>    ZoneId=3
> ```
>
> [MSDN-SECZONES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537183.aspx) gives an explanation of security zones.

(N.B. The original has a space between the colon and "Zone" but I think this is erroneous.)

You can find the ZoneIds in UrlMon.h in the SDK; there's an enum which equates to

```
enum URLZONE {
    URLZONE_LOCAL_MACHINE = 0,
    URLZONE_INTRANET      = 1,
    URLZONE_TRUSTED        = 2,
    URLZONE_INTERNET      = 3,
    URLZONE_RESTRICTED     = 4
};
```

(The original uses previous value + 1 rather than absolute values.)

As Hans says in the comments, these can be written with the standard Win32 file APIs [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and [WriteFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365747%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).
Firefox always writes Internet Zone, zone 3 - [Firefox code here](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/25d77f95d92c/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/win_safe_util.cc) (MPL/LGPL/GPL tri-license):

```
bool SetInternetZoneIdentifier(const FilePath& full_path) {
  const DWORD kShare = FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE;
  std::wstring path = full_path.value() + L":Zone.Identifier";
  HANDLE file = CreateFile(path.c_str(), GENERIC_WRITE, kShare, NULL,
                           OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
  if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == file)
    return false;

  const char kIdentifier[] = "[ZoneTransfer]\nZoneId=3";
  DWORD written = 0;
  BOOL result = WriteFile(file, kIdentifier, arraysize(kIdentifier), &written,
                          NULL);
  CloseHandle(file);

  if (!result || written != arraysize(kIdentifier)) {
    DCHECK(FALSE);
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

Alternatively there's an IE COM API [CLSID_PersistentZoneIdentifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537029%28VS.85%29.aspx) you can use to abstract this all for you.

Comment: Also just to add, [here's an alternate method](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20131104-00/?p=2753) to do the same using COM.

Answer (score -1):

It is not explicitly stated in RFC 3514, but today, due to increased security requirements, implementations should really retain the information of the presence or absence of the RFC3514 bit in a network transmission, when they write files out to disk, and vice-versa for reading from disk.

Comment: The question isn't about that bit specifically, and it's about how to actually write it to an NTFS stream alongside an .exe.

Comment: Are you talking about http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3514.html ? Did you notice it was written on April 1st ?

Comment: Did you notice that whenever someone referenced an April RFC to you, they were fully aware of being unserious? :D  - After all, MOTW does sound just like the Evil Bit.